# what does reducing losses in a GAN mean?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function, generative-adversarial-network

I have built a GAN and I am training it manually according to the the concept of optimizing several functions at a time. The loss of the discriminator and the generator is reduced at the same time optimally according to the equation I have employed, Though I am successful to reduce the loses of the generator and the discriminator to a great extent(better values than the original GAN training), however, the images generated are not good as the original GAN training. What could be the reason or how should I verify that inspite of losses being lowered the images are not good? Is there any intrinsic property of GAN that I need to keep in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the same network architecture and the same training data.

1. GANs usually take a very long time to train: did you train for long enough?
2. Initial latent variable may differ: did you use the same distribution? Or maybe the same seed?
3. The number of types you train your discriminator and generator: from experience, usually, we don't train for an equal number of times; in a sense, we alternate between the loss reduction - I tried 3-1 ratio, and it gave the best results.

Comment: To answer your questions:-
1. Yes I trained the GAN long enough with higher epochs
2. I did not use the same seed but I am running it many number of times. The images are not correct for any of the run.
3.  This customized loss optimization equation I am using for GAN has to update the generator and the discriminator  simulataneously as it shows the steepest descent direction for multiple functions. So I have to update simultaneously and not in the alternate fashion as we do in the classical GAN setting like first 4 times the Discriminator and then the generator once.

Comment: Can we check if the NAsh equilibrium is reaching or not? I mean if the images are not good.how can we verify the credibility of the GAN? I have plotted the losses. The values of the losses are good, I mean better than the classical training!

Comment: @Jeet generally speaking we assume that we reached the equilibrium when the loss of the discriminator is not decreasing at the expense of the generator (and the other way around), what is the case in your code? + check out this article it nicely shows the relationship between the two https://jonathan-hui.medium.com/gan-why-it-is-so-hard-to-train-generative-advisory-networks-819a86b3750b

Comment: Why does only reduing the losses in GAN does not ensure good images? I am optimizing the losses of the discriminator and the generator together and not one after the other. This is reducing the loss function more than what we can reduce optimizing them one after the other. However, the generated images are not good! What can be the reason for it?